# Read vs Write tables database design

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I have a user activity tracking log table where it logs all user activity as they occur. This is extremely high write table due to the in depth tracking of click by click tracking. Up to here the database design is perfect. Problem is the next step.

I need to output the data for the business folks + these people can query to fetch past activity data. Hence there is semi-medium to high read also. I do not like the idea of reading and writing from the same high traffic table.

So ideally I want to split the tables: The first one for quick writes (less to no fks), then copy that data over fully formatted & pulling in all the labels for the ids into a read table for reading use.

So questions:
1) Is this the best approach for me?
2) If i do keep 2 tables, how to keep them in sync? I cant copy the data to the read table instant as it writes to the write table - it will defeat the whole purpose of having seperate tables then, nor can i keep the read table to be old because the activity data tracked links with other user data like session_id, etc so if these IDs are not ready when their usecase calles for it the writes will fail.

I am using MySQL for user data and HBase for some large tables, with php codeignitor for my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have hard data which says you have a real performance issue with reading from this table?  Or could this just be "premature optimization"?

Comment: What does "extremely high write" mean? Please specify the number of transactions / megabytes per second. What kind of latency is acceptable (how up-to-date does the data have to be for reads)?

Comment: No performance done as yet. High writes because we are doing in depth user tracking of each movement on a page and logging tracked details every X seconds irrespective of activity. We dont have a number for X because that can be any number based on final performance. Ideally would like it to be at 2 seconds to get as real time tracking as possible, so if we do that you are looking at 1 recond at a minimum every 2 seconds per user. If you have 1 million user logged in then 1 millions writes every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, having 2 separate tables is the best approach. I've had the same problem to solve a few months ago, though for a daemon-type application and not a website.

Eventually I ended up with 1 MEMORY table keeping "live" data which is inserted/updated/deleted on almost every event and another table that had duplicates of the live data rows, but without the unnecesary system columns - my history table, which was used for reading only per request.

The live table is only relevant to the running process, so I don't care if the contained data is lost due to a server failure - whatever data needs to be read later is already stored in the history table. So ... there's no problem in duplicating the data in the two tables - your goal is performance, not normalization.